# Detect Home Button on Objective-C Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS framework in Objective-C and I need to detect when the home button is pressed while my framework is executing.

To describe a little better: on my final app, where I add the compiled framework, the user has to click a button that will make a call to my framework. The framework then opens the camera and tries to identify some objects and return a result.

My problem is: if the user clicks the home button while the camera is running and the app goes into background, I need my framework to end the process and return nil.

I already tried to use the methods:

```
- (void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *) application {}
- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *) application {}
- (void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *) application {}
- (void) applicationWillResign {}
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL) animated {}
```

None of them triggered when I pressed the home button.

Is there any other option to detecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot detect that the home button was pressed, BUT you can detect the result of it.

If your application gets sent to the background, you will get a `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`. You can listen for that using `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
- (void)initFramework {
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(willResignActive) 
                                               name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
                                             object:nil];
}

- (void)willResignActive {
    // do what you need to do,
    // e.g. cancel a running operation, 
    // call a callbackHandler with nil, etc.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // maybe also provide an explicit mechanism
    // by which the user of the framework can do this
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Nice! Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!